# Reducing queries for manytomany models in django

Tags: django

EDIT:
It turns out the real question is - how do I get select_related to follow the m2m relationships I have defined? Those are the ones that are taxing my system.  Any ideas?

I have two classes for my django app. The first (Item class) describes an item along with some functions that return information about the item.  The second class (Itemlist class) takes a list of these items and then does some processing on them to return different values.  The problem I'm having is that returning a list of items from Itemlist is taking a ton of queries, and I'm not sure where they're coming from.

```
class Item(models.Model):

# for archiving purposes
archive_id  = models.IntegerField()
users       = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='User_item_rel',
                                     related_name='users_set')

# for many to one relationship (tags)
tag         = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
sub_tag     = models.CharField(default='',max_length=40)

name        = models.CharField(max_length=40)
purch_date  = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
date_edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
price       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
buyer       = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Buyer_item_rel',
                                     related_name='buyers_set')
comments    = models.CharField(default='',max_length=400)
house_id    = models.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-purch_date']

def shortDisplayBuyers(self):
    if len(self.buyer_item_rel_set.all()) != 1:
        return "multiple buyers"
    else:
        return self.buyer_item_rel_set.all()[0].buyer.name
def listBuyers(self):
    return self.buyer_item_rel_set.all()

def listUsers(self):
    return self.user_item_rel_set.all()

def tag_name(self):
    return self.tag

def sub_tag_name(self):
    return self.sub_tag

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

and the second class:

```
class Item_list:

def __init__(self, list = None, house_id = None, user_id = None,
             archive_id = None, houseMode = 0):
    self.list = list
    self.house_id = house_id
    self.uid = int(user_id)
    self.archive_id = archive_id
    self.gen_balancing_transactions()
    self.houseMode = houseMode

def ret_list(self):
    return self.list
```

So after I construct Itemlist with a large list of items, Itemlist.ret_list() takes up to 800 queries for 25 items.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `len(self.buyer_item_rel_set.all())` change that to useing `count()`. It hurts (performance).

Answer (score 0):

Try using select_related

As per a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111778/lots-of-queries-from-django-foreignkey-fields)

Comment: So if I have a queryset that used select_related(), does filtering that queryset based on the related fields not touch the db either?

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar w/ the internals but I believe it will load and thus cache, related objects for the queryset, and run a whole lot less queries because of it. Although, if you're filtering related objects after already calling select_related I guess it makes sense that it would have to re-query the db. Try it and find out.

Answer (score 0):

Dan is right in telling you to use `select_related`.

`select_related` can be read about [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4).

What it does is return in the same query data for the main object in your queryset and the model or fields specified in the `select_related` clause.

So, instead of a query like:

```
select * from item
```

followed by several queries like this every time you access one of the item_list objects:

```
select * from item_list where item_id = <one of the items for the query above>
```

the ORM will generate a query like:

```
select item.*, item_list.* 
  from item a join item_list b
 where item a.id = b.item_id
```

In other words: it will hit the database once for all the data.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Works similarly to select_related, but can deal with relations selected_related cannot.  The join happens in python, but I've found it to be more efficient for this kind of work than the large # of queries.

[Related reading on the subject](http://tech.yipit.com/2013/01/20/making-django-orm-queries-faster/)